# Weblogic 10.3.6 Domain Wizard Could not create the JVM

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic, config, citrix

I try to run WLS Domain Wizard to create a new domain for WebLogic installed in virtual environment Citrix 12.3.400.3. It requires to run /Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/bin/config.exe
But as I do that the error arises immediately:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have installed there:

```
Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 51 (64-bit) - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
Java(TM) 6 Update 27 (64-bit) - C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
Java(TM) 7 Update 3 (64-bit) - C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Java(TM) SE Development Kit 7 Update 3 (64-bit) - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_3
```

Env var:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51

```
►java -version

java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Oracle JRockit(R) (build R28.2.7-7-155314-1.6.0_45-20130329-0646-windows-x86_64, compiled mode)
```

So, is there any hope to resolve this problem?

Comment: any chance you could paste some logs showing in more detail what exactly has happened?

Comment: If you give me a hint how to do that. I am not a Java developer at all (I was forced to do all those things). I presume it can be done by lunching the file from command line with some *trace* parameter (if yes, then which one?)?

Comment: try running config.cmd instead of config.exe.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin I have tried, but there no any log output appeared. Just the same alert and a new command line invitation. No any log files were created also :(

Comment: @srgg6701below link shows where logs live:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13739/logging_services.htm#WLLOG124

Any exceptions spotted in the logs should give some clues... (hopefully)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is here: https://community.oracle.com/message/12743335#

```
If multiple JDK installed on your computer, set JAVA_HOME before installing WLS. In your case: JDK 1.8 is not certified with the weblogic 10.3.6.
You must not set the JAVA_HOME variable after installation. The installer adds the correct Java Location in config files.
```

So I just change the JAVA_HOME variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03

Answer (score 2):

1. Open %HOME%\oracle_common\common\bin\commEnv.cmd
2. Set USER_MEM_ARGS environment variable after ":continue" tag
3. You can do this using below  (or with higer values):

   SET USER_MEM_ARGS=-Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:MaxHeapSize=512m
4. Try to re-create default domain again

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the weblogic installation, set required paths correctly and then proceed as like the below steps

Example: 
Assuming that JDK is already installed in your machine at the path:  C:\Java\jdk & 
wls_xxxxx.jar file is exist at C:\Software.

1. Run the command prompt as an administrator.
2. Set PATH,JAVA_HOME,_JAVA_OPTIONS from command prompt as like below

   C:\Windows\system32>set PATH=C:\Java\jdk\bin

   C:\Windows\system32>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk

   C:\Windows\system32>SET _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms512M
3. Change the directory to locate your weblogic jar file.

   C:\Windows\system32>CD C:\Software
4. Run below command to start the weblogic installation

   C:\Software>java -jar wls_xxxxx.jar

Note: Choose java version as recommended in the weblogic installation guide.